# function to store the clicked element and perform an action

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
HB.formsSubmitButton.activatingButton = function(element) {
    element.attr('disabled', true)
           .parent()
           .addClass(HB.formsSubmitButton.submitButtonStyle);
}
```

it basically adds a spinner on the button you have clicked on>

However now I have a form where you have a submit and cancel button, how can I change `HB.formsSubmitButton.activatingButton` to accept both buttons but only perform the function based on which one you have clicked?

Comment: you can check attributes of the `element` to decide what action to perform. :)

Comment: the action will always be the same regardless of the button that you are clicking on...  the problems is I have 2 buttons and in my function I can only pass one.